# Finding Same Basis of Quotient Vector Space as in this Paper

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

I'm trying to follow this paper: [Flows, scaling, and the control of moment hierarchies for stochastic chemical reaction
networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08386.pdf)
.  Sorry for poor use of vectors, couldn't figure out how to get the vectors not to take a whole line.

Avoiding the physical details behind these matrices, there are two example matrices they give, **A** and **Y**.  The examples they use are

**A** = \begin{bmatrix}-\alpha & \epsilon & 0 \\ \alpha & -2\epsilon & \beta \\ 0 & \epsilon & -\beta \end{bmatrix}

and **Y** = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.

Now, there are two vector sets of interest, the basis of ker(**YA**)$^\perp$ and 
 the basis of the quotient space ker(**YA**)/ker(**A**).  Given these, I've calculated that

ker(**A**) = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\alpha \\ 1/\epsilon \\ 1/\beta \end{bmatrix}

and ker(**YA**) (there are two vectors in this basis, sorry for not having in same line) = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\alpha \\ 0 \\ 1/\beta \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}

So I get the basis for  ker(**YA**)$^\perp$ = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ 0 \\ -\beta \end{bmatrix},

To calculate the basis for ker(**YA**)/ker(**A**), I just found a vector orthogonal to ker(**A**) in the vector space of ker(**YA**), being = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\alpha \\ -1/\epsilon \\ 1/\beta \end{bmatrix}.

However, this answer is obviously wrong as it is not orthogonal to ker(**A**).

However, in the text they get different answers than the paper (page 17, the row vectors in the parentheses of the last line of equation 64),

basis for ker(**YA**)$^\perp$ = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ 0 \\ -\beta \end{bmatrix} and

basis for ker(**YA**)/ker(**A**) = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \beta^2 \\ -\epsilon(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) \\ \beta \alpha^2 \end{bmatrix}

And I'm not sure what I did wrong, could someone help me out with where I went wrong?

Comment: I'm confused by this.  $(1, 1, 1)\mathbf A = (0, 0, 0),$ but why are you writing it as a column vector?  If you really mean a column vector, then it's not in the kernel, is it?  I would say the kernel of $\mathbf A$ is $<(1/\alpha, 1/\epsilon, 1/\beta)^T>$.

Comment: Sorry, all vectors I've put are transposes.  I'll edit that... yes they show should be row vectors, thank you

Comment: You must be misinterpreting the way in which they identify matrices with linear maps. $YA$ has to be a map from height 3 column vectors to $\mathbb{R}$: then the kernel will have the transposes of $(\beta,0,\alpha)$ and $(0,1,0)$ as a basis, and the orthogonal subspace would be spanned by the transpose of $(\alpha,0,-\beta)$ as they claim. Equally you have to think of $A$ as acting on the left on column vectors, not on the right on row vectors.

Comment: for the vector ($\beta$,0,$\alpha$), I get that it is a vector in the kernel of **YA** iff $\alpha$ = $\beta$.  So then the vector ($\beta$,0,$\alpha$) must be (1,0,1), right?

Comment: Also, I believe the kernel should be column vectors, because it is the set Ax = 0, correct?

Comment: Edit: I was solving ($\alpha$, 0, -$\beta$ | 0), giving, $\alpha$ = $\beta$, but I see that multiplying by ($\beta$, 0, $\alpha$) also gives 0, but ($\beta$, 0, $\beta$) does not.  Am I doing something very wrong in my computing of the kernel?

Comment: Yes, all the vectors are column vectors.

Comment: The basis for ker(**YA**)$^\perp$ makes more sense, but what about the basis for the quotient space?

Comment: In computing the kernels, remember that all the matrices act on column vectors, with the column vectors written on the right.  Your computation of the kernel of A is incorrect.  See my first comment.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, I didn't normalize to unity when I row reduced... its been a long time.  I see then how you get the answer you get.  So then for ker(**A**) I obtain what you have in first comment, transpose of (1/$\alpha$, 1/$\epsilon$, 1/$\beta$).  Then for ker(**YA**) I get a basis of (1/$\alpha$, 0 , 1/$\beta$), and (0,1,0).

Comment: For the product space then, I find the vector orthogonal to (1/$\alpha$, 1/$\epsilon$, 1/$\beta$) in the ker(**YA**) basis, which I take to be ($\alpha$,-$\epsilon$,$\beta$); there is only one vector since dim(V/U) = dim(V)-dim(U), and here that is 1.  Obviously this is different from the vector they obtain, what is wrong with my procedure?

Comment: Would you please update the question with the current results of your calculations?   I'm having a bit of difficulty following the comments.  Note however $(1/\alpha, 1/\epsilon, 1/\beta) \cdot (\alpha, -\epsilon, \beta) = 1 \ne0$

Comment: Edited it.  I see what you mean with dot product.  I just don't see how you find the basis for a quotient space though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis you give for $\ker(\mathbf{YA})$ is correct.  You're correct that the the dimension of $\mathbf V = \ker(\mathbf{YA})/\ker(\mathbf{A})$ is one, so the basis has only one element.  Of course, the elements of $\mathbf V$ are cosets, so that we really want something of the form $\mathbf X + \ker(\mathbf A)$ as the basis element, but I assume the paper is just leaving out the $"+\ker(\mathbf A)"$.

In any event, any element in $\ker(\mathbf{YA})\setminus \ker(\mathbf{A})$ will serve as the required $\mathbf X,$ and at first I could not figure out why they have chosen such a complicated-looking $\mathbf X$ in the paper.  By inspection, either of the basis vectors that you give for $\ker(\mathbf{YA})$ will work.

I believe, however that I have figured it out, at least in part.  The given vector is orthogonal to $\ker(\mathbf A),$ and this must be what they wanted to achieve.  It is not enough, as you suggest in your answer, to pick a vector orthogonal to $\ker(\mathbf A);$ it must also be an element of $\ker(\mathbf{YA}).$

So, the elements of $\ker(\mathbf{YA})$ are of the form $(x/\alpha, y, x/\beta)^T, x,y \in \mathbb R,$ and we must have $$(x/\alpha, y, x/\beta)\cdot (1/\alpha, 1/\varepsilon, 1/\beta) = 0.$$  This gives, $$y = \frac{-\varepsilon x}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$$ We get the vector from the paper on setting $x=\alpha \beta.$  I have no explanation for why they chose this particular value for $x.$  Some desire for symmetry perhaps?

Comment: That would be great, thank you!  I've been confused on how they obtained that vector.  In the paper, they are trying to use vectors such that **A**(a$^T$a + b$^T$b) = c**A**, where a is the basis vector of ker(**YA**)$^\perp$, and b is the basis vector of the quotient space.  With the vector they obtain, c = (a$^2$ + b$^2$)

Comment: Okay.  If you need to see the details of that calculation, you should really ask a second question.  It's okay to refer back to this question, so you don't necessarily have to type everything again, just enough so a reader will understand what you're asking.

Comment: I see, no not asking for more work, just a different angle haha.  Thank you for the help!  However, when I solve for y, I get y = -$\epsilon$(($\beta^2$ + $\alpha^2$)x/($\beta^2\alpha^2$), and x = $\beta^2\alpha^2$ gets their vector.  I don't see exactly why they chose such a particular value, except that perhaps it solves the condition I commented.  As you say it's a separate question, and I highly appreciate your help getting to their vector!  Thank you!

Comment: The site 's rules are that one shouldn't ask new questions in comments.  The goal is that the answers have lasting value, so that people can find solutions to their problems without having to ask a question.  That's easier to achieve if the discussions in the comments don't involve new questions.  (I'm not criticizing you, just explaining.)